# T-SQL: Can a subquery in the SELECT clause implicitly reference a table in the main outer query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, subquery, intellisense

In T-SQL, is it possible to have a subquery in the SELECT clause that *implicitly* references tables in the main, outer query? For example:

```
select NAME,
       case when exists (select o.ORDERID) then 1 else 0 end BUYER
  from CUSTOMER c
  left join ORDER o
    on c.CUSTID = o.CUSTID
```

In other words, can I write subqueries without a FROM clause?

Intellisense seems to recognize outer table aliases in subqueries, but I can't find any documentation that says this is acceptable T-SQL. I can certainly run some of my own tests, but I also wanted to check with the community. Thanks.

Comment: Your `FROM clause` makes all the fields of `CUSTOMER c` and `ORDER o` available to you in the `SELECT clause` without needing to use select yet again. You should always prefix each field by the table alias; so Name should be `c.Name` (assuming it is from c)

Comment: You're right, it's better practice to always prefix. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is valid syntax.

A `SELECT` without a `FROM` is treated as though selecting from a single row table. Referencing columns from the outer query is required for correlated sub queries and is perfectly valid there.

The particular query you have makes no sense though. It will always evaluate to `1` as that subquery always returns a single row (with a single column containing the corresponding `o.OrderId`) going into the `EXISTS` check.

Probably you want to check `o.OrderId IS NULL`

```
SELECT NAME, 
       CASE 
         WHEN o.ORDERID IS NULL THEN 0 
         ELSE 1 
       END BUYER, 
FROM   CUSTOMER c 
       LEFT JOIN ORDER o 
              ON c.CUSTID = o.CUSTID
```

Where it does make sense to use this type of syntax is in a null safe equality check.

e.g.

```
SELECT A, 
       B, 
       CASE 
         WHEN EXISTS (SELECT T.A 
                      EXCEPT 
                      SELECT T.B) THEN 1 
         ELSE 0 
       END AS DistinctFrom 
FROM   T
```

Is equivalent to

```
SELECT A, 
       B, 
       CASE 
         WHEN A <> B 
               OR ( A IS NULL 
                    AND B IS NOT NULL ) 
               OR ( A IS NOT NULL 
                    AND B IS NULL ) THEN 1 
         ELSE 0 
       END AS DistinctFrom 
FROM   T
```